# How to add my partitions to home folder side panel?

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

I'm using ubuntu 16.10. I can't see my partitions on my left side bar in home folder. someone help me with simple process.

Comment: What partitions should be there?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I think he has some partitions other than, `/home`  `/root`, I think he is talking about those

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Probably some external or additional drive, we don't know and that was the point of my request for clarification. Without it the question will most likely be closed as "unclear" and that is what 'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @CelticWarrior it's definitely unclear, he might not even return here, i'm trying to answer it anyway

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output `sudo lsblk -f` and the content of `/etc/fstab`? Which partition(s) do you want to have displayed in the side bar of the file manager?

Comment: I'm not technically strong in ubuntu basics. If any one have found my question to be false, please excuse me.  I need my drives such as D and E drives(as in case of windows) to be appear in my default file explorer. Is it okay @SumeetDeshmukh ??

Comment: @sam did my answer worked?

Answer (score 8):

If What your trying to achieve is to list all the partitions from the **other partitions** section in your Nautilus (default File manager) left side panel. then that's quite hard, Easy thing to do would be to add Bookmarks of those Partition, To do that

1. Open your **partition**.
2. And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
3. A **Bookmark** should appear in the left side panel.
4. You can click this bookmark to navigate to that partition (but that partition should be mounted)

If the bookmark has a weird looking long name and that doesn't represent the name of your partition, you might want to [change it's mount point](https://askubuntu.com/a/904564/665251)

Another approach would be to install another File Manager that supports this Feature by default, **Nemo** is a nice file manager, you can install it by pasting following commands one by one into your Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> To open terminal)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/nemo3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

If you like **Nemo** and want to make it your default File manager, then run these commands one by one as well

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```