# How to change hard drive name

Tags: rename, device-name

my hard drive is located in `/media/ronin_cunningham/408242E58242DED2` and I want to change the name **408242E58242DED2** to **StorageDevice**. How would I do this from the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to do this through command, then please update your question with output of `lsblk`

Comment: or this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus

Comment: Unclear if you want to change the partition / file system label, or just change the mountpoint. The answer below sounds like what you want (mountpoint only), though the "duplicate" question changes the label too

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to do it with GUI

- Go to **disk app** (through Unity Dash or terminal with `gnome-disks` command)
- Choose your **partition**
- Click the little **gear** icon [image: Gear icon]
- Select **Edit mount options**
- Toggle  **Automatic Mount Option** to   *Off*
- Edit mount point to `/media/ronin_cunningham/StorageDevice`

On a side note, this will also enable your partition to be mounted automatically on start up, **If** you don't want that to happen then make sure to

- Un-mark **Mount at Startup**

You'd want to do this if your **Bootup times** are slow

---

[image: screenshot of gnome-disk app]
*Theme might not look exactly like this*

Comment: @DKBoss should I edit that in my answer?

Comment: That's totally your call! If you feel it may improve your answer, do so. Otherwise, your answer is fine as it is.

Comment: This worked, you guys are very helpful to Linux noobs like me, thank you!

Comment: Does this require a reboot to take effect? If so is there anything I can manually run to update this without a reboot. (I tried the above and it still gets mounted to the wrong Mount Point, I guess I will try rebooting but I would have preferred it if that weren't required.)

Comment: Okay that was not the issue. It still does not work. It is still mounting to the previous default location.